# Excel forms: identify unused code

Tags: excel, vba

I am updating an [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) app written by someone else (of course :)

I found lots of unused `Sub CommandButtonXX_Click()` subs, and I am not always sure if the button still exists. Is there a way (program, VBE interface, external tool) to do some cleanup while avoiding to delete the *still in use* code ?

The list at the top of the properties box does seem to be reliable, since it is kind of *context sensitive*: if you're in a tab, it displays only items of that tab.

Comment: nice question. I'd wouldn't try to automate the suppression through VBA only because that would be quite hard to code and you might get undexpected results. If you try it "by hand", the listbox in the VBE should be exhaustive of the remaining buttons.

Comment: @JMAx: I do not really look to delete code automatically, just a way to be sure that ButtonXX is really gone, so I can delete the corresponding sub manually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An interesting question!

1. I have significantly modified Pearson's code [Listing All Procedures In A Module](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) to find all `CommandButtonXX_Click` code on each worksheet (excluding other subs),
2. then tried to match each `CommandButtonXX_Click` code to an actual button on that sheet.
3. If there is no match the button is deleted, and a `Msgbox` at the end lists all deletions

Coding the VBA Editor can be problematic so pls save your work beforehand. I have avoided early binding with the Extensibility library that Pearson has used.

***[4 Oct 2012: Updated to work on UserForms rather than Sheets]***

```
       SConst vbext_ct_MSForm = 3
Sub ListProcedures()
    Dim VBProj
    Dim VBComp
    Dim CodeMod
    Dim LineNum As Long
    Dim NumLines As Long
    Dim ProcName As String
    Dim ObjButton
    Dim ProcKind
    Dim strBadButtons As String
    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    For Each VBComp In VBProj.vbcomponents
        If VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_MSForm Then
            Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
            With CodeMod
                LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
                Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
                    ProcName = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, 0)
                    If ProcName Like "CommandButton*_Click" Then
                        Set ObjButton = Nothing
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Set ObjButton = VBComp.Designer.Controls(Replace(ProcName, "_Click", vbNullString))
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        If ObjButton Is Nothing Then
                            strBadButtons = strBadButtons & CodeMod.Name & "-" & Replace(ProcName, "_Click", vbNullString) & vbNewLine
                            .DeleteLines .ProcStartLine(ProcName, 0), .ProcCountLines(ProcName, 0)
                        End If
                    End If
                    LineNum = LineNum + 1
                Loop
            End With
        End If
    Next
    If Len(strBadButtons) > 0 Then MsgBox "Bad Buttons deleted" & vbNewLine & strBadButtons
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a nice start, thanks...except that I am looking for buttons in *Forms*, not in Worksheets. I am working on it, based on your code, and will publish my updates when done.

Comment: No probs, it shouldn't take much modification, Pearson's link should be helpful in adapting the code, else let me know if you'd like me to tweak it.

Comment: Updated to look at UserForms.

Comment: Fantastic ! Thanks a lot. Too bad I can't accept it twice ;-)

Comment: Glad to have helped, I really enjoyed this one :)

Answer (score 6):

There's a free add-in tool called MZ-Tools that can be used to identify unused procedures (it can do a lot more as well). Here is the link: http://www.mztools.com/v3/download.aspx

Comment: I installed MZ-Tools and it does look very useful. But I couldn't readily find the functionality to indentify the unused procedures. Can you pls post a screenshot? :)

Comment: I couldn't find that feature either.

Comment: I've had it recommended to me, but I've never used it before. According to the website: "The source code review can be launched automatically (or you can be asked) when you make the executable of a project, that is, clicking some of the File | Make ... menus."

Answer (score 4):

I'm developing **[Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com)**, an open-source COM add-in for the VBE written in C# that has a *code inspections* feature that, as of version 1.3 (next release!), will include an inspection that does exactly that:

[image: "Procedure 'CommandButton5_Click' is never used"]

This inspection isn't specifically looking for unused *click handlers* as the accepted answer is doing (and if any `CommandButtonX` was renamed to anything meaningful, then the accepted answer will not find them - *but that's not what the original post was about*) - it's looking for *procedures that are never called*, assuming `Public` procedures and functions in a standard module (i.e. exposed to the host application as "macros" or "user-defined functions"), are used outside of the VBA code.

This version only finds controls on *forms*, not on *worksheets* - so handler procedures for ActiveX controls located on a worksheet would actually show up as false positives.

Comment: FWIW I've edited to highlight that your [very nice] answer actually addresses the OP.

Comment: Good luck with Rubberduck - look forward to seeing it

Comment: @brettdj thanks! IMO that inspection [isn't the best, most impactful and life-changing upcoming feature](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8ruUn.png) though ;) *(cough)* *rename refactoring* *(cough)*