# Late Binding VBIDE.VBE in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Is it possible to late bind the VBIDE.VBE object in Excel? For example:

```
Dim VBAEditor As VBIDE.VBE
```

Instead becomes something similar to this (late-binded):

```
Dim VBAEditor As Object: set VBAEditor = CreateObject ("VBIDE.VBE")
```

My goal is to avoid having to manually go in an select the checkbox for the "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3" reference.

### SOLUTION

Using the feedback below, I was able to do programmatically add the "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3" reference dynamically. Solution is as follows:

```
Sub mainFunction()

    Call AddLib("VBIDE", "{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", 5, 3)

    ' Bunch of working code goes here

End Sub

'******************************************************************************
'AddLib: Adds a library reference to this script programmatically, so that
'        libraries do not need to be added manually.
'******************************************************************************
Private Function AddLib(libName As String, guid As String, major As Long, minor As Long)

    Dim exObj As Object: Set exObj = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Dim vbProj As Object: Set vbProj = exObj.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Dim chkRef As Object

    ' Check if the library has already been added
    For Each chkRef In vbProj.References
        If chkRef.Name = libName Then
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If
    Next

    vbProj.References.AddFromGuid guid, major, minor

CleanUp:
    Set vbProj = Nothing
End Function
```

I was heavily inspired by [this stack article on dynamic referencing in excel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically-vba-excel)

Comment: Why would you need to do this? That reference is the same across all versions anyway, and you can simply late bind as an alternative.

Comment: @Rory, I wanted to make it easier for people to import and use my script in their excel document. This is another reason why I moved to GUID for the same reason you stated; GUID references are the same across all versions. I need to keep the `chkRef` in the code above as well to avoid an error related to "objects of the same name" being used. The code above does what I need it to do now.

Comment: Why not late bind then? It's a lot simpler and doesn't need any specific user settings in the Trust Center, unlike what you're doing.

Comment: @Rory, I see what your mentioning about late-binding. I have changed my code above to late-bind the excel application instead. However, I am not familiar with the API enough to late bind VBProject to get around the trust setting. Any hints, documentation, or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @Rory, if VBProject is a property I believe cannot use getObject to grab it. How does one get around not using VBProject to check for configured references?

Comment: You can't. Any access to the VBProject requires trusted access to be set. (I think I misunderstood what you were up to and thought you only wanted access to set the reference)

Comment: Ok great. Thank you @Rory for pointing out my missing late-bind though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as per [Excel forms: identify unused code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445723/excel-forms-identify-unused-code/7446583#7446583) you can use late binding

```
Dim VBProj
Dim VBComp
Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
For Each VBComp In VBProj.vbcomponents
```

etc

Comment: In my code I currently use `Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject` and `VBAEditor As VBIDE.VBE`. The VBAEditor allows me to check the references currently configured in the IDE itself.

[I was heavily inspired by this stack article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically-vba-excel). They do not appear to be the same object. Can I do the same with VBAEditor as VBProject?

Comment: @Jake88 late-binding means you're *not* declaring `As VBIDE.*`, and *not* getting IntelliSense for the members of whatever objects you're using, which means you'd better know the API like the palm of your hand. `VBIDE.VBE` is the "root" object of the API; it has a `.VBProjects` collection that contains `VBProject` objects, one of which corresponds to `ActiveWorkbook.VBProject` - note that there's a security setting that must be enabled in the host app (Excel) to allow access to that object.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it all working. I'll share what I was trying to do in my question above.